# How to subset data for whole county to just portion in particular city using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes, county

I have a shapefile of all of Riverside County. It includes parcels with and without site addresses. I do not have a city limits shapefile. How can I locate the boundary of the city that I need to pull, so I can only grab the attribute data and spatial data for that city and not the WHOLE county?

I tried to do a selection on the site address and used city as a locator, but not all parcels have a site address, which leaves out lots of parcels in that selection.

Can someone provide me with info on how to make a selection on city which will include all parcels, even ones with out a site address? I am using ArcGIS 10.3.

Comment: There are many possible approaches, and they depend on your data. Are there other possibly identifying attributes in the county data shapefile? Do you have any other data (e.g., city limits shapefile) you can use to select the parcels using a sort of overlay? Please give us some more information about your data so we can suggest things.

Comment: What software are you using? Is the question how to select certain records, or where to find a particular municipal boundary? Two very different questions.

Comment: Hello, I have a shapefile of all of riverside county. It includes parcels with site addresses and parcels without site addresses. I do not have a city limits shapefile. I am using ARCGIS 10.3. I would like to select records in a particular municipal boundary based on the city name. I can't do it based on site address, as some parcels do not have an address.

Comment: I work for Riverside County.  You can get the Countywide Active Geodatabase that contains the boundaries of the Cities in Riverside County from http://gis.rivcoit.org/GISData.aspx.  You can select a particular City and use that shape with the Select by Location tool to select all of the parcels contained within the selected City. You should use a small negative buffer distance with the tool to avoid selecting parcels outside of the City that touch the City boundary.  See the Select by Location help at:  http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001700000072000000

Comment: We need you to take the [Tour] to learn more about how to frame and [edit] your questions to improve them here.

Comment: You should edit that information into your question using the button at the lower left rather than posting it as a comment. My first suggestion, already made by Richard and Emil, would be to locate a shapefile with municipal boundaries - many counties with GIS data available have that as one of the layers. And since there's only one Riverside county in the US apparently, Richard has given you a link to find it. From there you can do a select by location. Note if the boundaries don't match, you may need to look into apportionment depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Where can I find a shapefile of city boundaries in the US?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/where-can-i-find-a-shapefile-of-city-boundaries-in-the-us) to find city polygons, download, and add it to ArcMap.

- Select the appropriate city.
- Then perform a Select By Location on your parcel features that intersect the selected city polygon.